# Mean curvature of surfaces

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

In this [article](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Analytic-Calculation-of-Capillary-Bridge-Properties-Gagneux-Millet/8d6f9ca3b1a7b02e53691c654c86dba606a4240b), the authors in table 1 shows that for unduloid (that is rotation of an elliptic curve), shows that unduloid whether the meridian curvature (the profile curvature) is convex or concave have always same sign of mean curvature (which is positive in physical terms). I was trying to understand why?

in laplace equation we have:

$$-\frac{r''}{(1+r'^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{r(1+r'^2)^{1/2}} =   2 H$$

the first term is the meridian principle curvature and the second one is the one along the circular cross section that is parallel to axis of revolution. the second term is always positive for $r>0$ and due to the fact it is circular so always convex. the first term might be negative or positive based on $r''$. Can we say then based on this table in this study that ellipses have curvatures always small than circles? Because it is not the case for nodoid, the competition between both give positive and negative mean curvature, but for unduloid is always positive, i don't find a good interpretation for this.

Comment: First, you do not mean elliptic curve. The unduloid comes from following a fixed point as you roll an *ellipse* along a line. I do not know what kind of explanation you're looking for. But the calculations on pp. 110-111 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/users/user317/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf) might be helpful.

Comment: @TedShifrin That's right. My question was why (2H) is always positive (i.e. negative in your definition since you are using the math convention in example 2 of page 110) for the case of unduloid, irrespective of the kind of the meridian curvature that might be negative or positive (depending if convex or concave)

Comment: Mean curvature of the unduloid is constant. The sign is a matter of orientation.